# Left Ventricle vs. Right Ventricle size in different Animals

Tags: zoology, human-anatomy, cardiology, heart-output

Why are the right ventricles in chicken hearts significantly smaller than the left ventricles, whereas in cows the two ventricles are of roughly equal size.

Comment: The question is interesting +1. Can you please add a reference and/or a figure showing that they differ? If you happen to know whether these traits are shared among all birds and all mammals respectively, that'd be great to state it.

Comment: Of all the pictures I've found googling, the ventricle sizes of humans, chickens and cows appear to be: left ventricle bigger than right ventricle.. ? add a reference please.

Comment: I don't know where you got your information, but it's not correct. The bovine (cow) heart is very much like the human heart in that the right ventricle is significantly smaller than the left. It's important to note that the difference is in muscle mass, not volume of blood each ventricle holds. More muscle is needed to pump blood through the body than through the lungs.